# add timer/counter clock in limesurvey template

Tags: javascript, limesurvey

I have looked over web for process to add timer in limesurvey template but i don't have any solution. we want to integrate timer in survey of limesurvey but we don't know how we should that.If any one know how this can b performed please describe it.

Thanks in advance